# How can you translate prolog rules and query into first order logic?

Tags: prolog, first-order-logic

I am trying to understand how to translate the prolog rule

```
brother(g(x), g(y)) :- brother(x,y).
brother(n,n).
```

to first order logic.

is `∀x,y(brother(x,y) -> brother(g(x), g(y))` a correct answer?

Comment: The program text has multiple syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it

Answer (score 1):

No, the answer is not correct.

First, decide whether `x`, `y` and `n` in the Prolog program are actually meant to be logical *variables*. In that case, you need to change the program: A Prolog variable begins with an uppercase letter or underscore. So, suppose you change the program to:

```
brother(g(X), g(Y)) :- brother(X, Y).
brother(N, N).
```

Then the translation you give is *still* not sufficient to capture the declarative meaning of this logic program.

For example, using just the implication you give, can you derive *a single statement* that actually *holds*?